# Is it allowed to cast unordered_map to map?

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary

As title says, is it allowed? If not, are they sharing the same interface or abstract class anyway? I did not find any reference from online documents. but looks unordered_map and map are using the same functions.

Comment: Just because they have the same _API_ doesn't mean that they work the same way internally. Casting one to the other will probably make your code to fail in quite odd ways.

Comment: Why would you *need* to cast them? You can just use the consistent interface through templated algorithms.

Comment: Perhaps this point about the consistent interface is worth labouring a bit: they're written that way not just because it's easier to remember, but also specifically to allow the templated algorithms @KerrekSB mentions.  For further reading, look up _duck typing_.

Comment: The old program uses unordered_map. Now I need sorted iteration over the container and need to refactor the code. I just wonder if I can keep most code unchanged by casting. now it looks impossible, and I have to change code like unordered_map::iterator to map::iterator.

Comment: @Richard: That's why well-written, maintainable C++ code uses **typedefs**, so you would just say `EmployeeSalaries::iterator`. Typedefs make your code *local*, so that a change (of type, in this case) only has to be performed in and affects one place.

Comment: Or possibly better than just a typedef: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, they're totally different and even if you force it with `reinterpret_cast`, it'll just go horribly wrong at runtime (ie, the dreaded Undefined Behaviour).

They're both STL containers, so deliberately have consistent interfaces.
That doesn't mean they're the same thing internally.

Answer (score 7):

They're two unrelated types. If you want to construct one based on the other, you need to use constructors that take iterator range (C++11):

```
template <class InputIterator>
map(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
    const Compare& comp = Compare(), const Allocator& = Allocator());

template <class InputIterator>
unordered_map(InputIterator f, InputIterator l,
              size_type n = see below,
              const hasher& hf = hasher(),
              const key_equal& eql = key_equal(),
              const allocator_type& a = allocator_type());
```

Answer (score 1):

STL classes do not use virtual functions; there is no consistent base class you can cast through (ie, there's no equivalent to Java's `java.util.Map`). You can't cast between `std::unordered_map` and `std::map` any more than you could cast between `HashMap` and `TreeMap` in java - they're completely different types and cannot be used equivalently.

If you want a function to be able to take multiple types of STL containers, just use a template function:

```
template<typename Map>
void somefunc(Map &mymap) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reinterpret cast one thing to any other thing, even if it makes no sense. The compiler won't stop you if you force it, which is essentially what reinterpret cast is. Casting map to unordered_map makes no sense & won't work.

Why do you want to cast map to unordered_map? They have the same interface. You gain nothing by casting it.

Comment: You can try to cast, but you can't use the result.

Comment: If it makes no sense, how useful is it?

Comment: I never said it was useful. I just stated the fact that the compiler will let you do it even if it makes no sense.

Comment: I think you want to make the "it makes no sense" part a lot stronger. As it stands your answer looks like you're implying it is useful, even if that wasn't your intention.

Comment: You can only `reinterpret_cast` pointers, references and integral types.  You can't `reinterpret_cast<map>` or `reinterpret_cast<unordered_map>`.